# I get the following error for my assembly language

Tags: assembly, irvine32

If it relates to the size, I thought DWORD was supposed to go into a 32-bit register. 
The error is: c:\Irvine\SmallWin.inc(11): error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
valA DWORD 12 
valB DWORD 10
valC DWORD 12
valD DWORD 10   

.code
main proc
mov eax,valA
mov ebx,valB
mov ecx,valC
mov edx,valD        
sub eax,ebx
sub ecx,edx
add eax,ecx
mov valA, eax
call WriteInt               

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Looks okay, which line is the error on? Also, is this `SmallWin.inc`?

Comment: It never gave a line for the error :/ And yes it is.

Comment: `11` is the line number, if you used this exact file that's `valC DWORD 12` which should of course work just as well as the other ones. Unless maybe `valC` is already defined or a reserved word. Try renaming it.

Comment: Yes, that was it for some reason :/ Thank you :)